# Duda con respecto a como añadir contenido de un archivo de texto a un Arraylist en Java

Tags: java, arraylist, scanner

He estado haciendo el siguiente método para poder leer la información de un archivo y luego guardarlos en una lista que se llama "lista"

```
public static ArrayList<Perro> leeArchivo(String nombreArchivo) {

    Perro p;
    Scanner scan = null;
    String nombre, raza;
    double peso;
    boolean pedigree, vacunas;
    ArrayList<Perro> lista = new ArrayList<Perro>();

    try {
        scan = new Scanner (new FileReader(nombreArchivo));
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            // leer los perros del archivo y 
            // guardarlos en la lista llamada "lista"
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println(e);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
         System.err.println(e);
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e){
         System.err.println(e);
    }
    finally{
         scan.close();
    }

    return lista;
}
```

En el ciclo `While` es donde se debe de meter esta instrucción pero he probado cosas como `lista.add(scan.hasNext())` entre otras y no puedo resolver el problema, cual es la forma correcta en la que se puede añadir cualquier contenido de información de un archivo txt a una lista ?

Como información extra, el archivo txt tiene el siguiente formato:

> portos    /   mastin  /   90.0    /   true    /    true

Comment: No entiendo porque eliminaste tu pregunta anterior que era exactamente igual a esta. lo que lees del archivo, lo tenes que poner en un objeto del tipo Perro y luego meter ese objeto en la lista.

Comment: Hola revisa por favor [ask] para que realices preguntas que sean atractivas para la comunidad y te pueda apoyar de una mejor manera y realiza el [tour] del sitio, recuerda también votar si la respuesta pudo solucionar el problema planteado en tus preguntas, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy importante que definas cual es la estructura del archivo que lees, en este caso :

```
portos / mastin / 90.0 / true / true
```

en este caso tu archivo además de los atributos contiene el caracter "/" por lo tanto cada vez que obtengas un valor mediante  `scan.next();` debes llamar nuevamente  `scan.next();` para evitar el valor de "/".

Además también tienes que hacer uso de `Double.parseDouble(...)` y `Boolean.parseBoolean(...)` si es que tus setter reciben el formato Double y Boolean

Ejemplo:

```
             //Crea objeto  
             Perro perro = new Perro();
             //Obtiene valores
             perro.setNombre(scan.next());             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setRaza(scan.next());             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setPeso(Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setPedigree(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setVacunas(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));                    

             //agrega perro a la lista.
             lista.add(perro);
```

Para que lo anterior funcione, recuerda que tu objeto Perro debe tener un constructor vació:

```
public class Perro implements Comparable<Perro>{

    //Constructor     
    public Perro() {        
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

---

Este sería el ejemplo completo:

```
    public static ArrayList<Perro> leeArchivo(String nombreArchivo) {

    Perro p;
    Scanner scan = null;
    String nombre, raza;
    double peso;
    boolean pedigree, vacunas;
    ArrayList<Perro> lista = new ArrayList<Perro>();

    try {
        scan = new Scanner (new FileReader(nombreArchivo));        
        while (scan.hasNext()) {

            // leer los perros del archivo y 
            // guardarlos en la lista llamada "lista"   

             //Crea objeto  
             Perro perro = new Perro();
             //Obtiene valores
             perro.setNombre(scan.next());             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setRaza(scan.next());             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setPeso(Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setPedigree(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));             
             scan.next(); //Evita caracter "/".
             perro.setVacunas(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));                    

             //agrega perro a la lista
             lista.add(perro);

        }                
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println(e);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
         System.err.println(e);
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e){
         System.err.println(e);
    }
    finally{
         scan.close();
    }

    return lista;
}
```