# Leer un archivo txt y regesar un ArrayList con la informacion JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito leer datos de un archivo txt, en este mismo se encuentras datos de diferentes perros y el formato es el siguiente:

portos  mastin     90.0 true    true

rambo   granDanes   80.0    true    false

patsy   terrier 8.0 false   true

nombre, raza, peso, pedigree, vacunas

Tengo mi código que permite mi lectura del archivo que es el siguiente:

public static ArrayList< Perro > leeArchivo(String nombreArchivo) {

```
        Perro p;
        Scanner scan = null;
        String nombre, raza;
        double peso;
        boolean pedigree, vacunas;
        ArrayList<Perro> lista = new ArrayList<Perro>();

        try {
            scan = new Scanner (new FileReader(nombreArchivo));        
            while (scan.hasNext()) {


                 Perro perro = new Perro(nombre, raza, peso, pedigree, vacunas);

                 perro.setNombre(scan.next());             

                 perro.setRaza(scan.next());             

                 perro.setPeso(Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));             

                 perro.setPedigree(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));             

                 perro.setVacunas(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));                    

                 //agrega perro a la lista
                 lista.add(perro);

            }                
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             System.err.println(e);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
             System.err.println(e);
        } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e){
             System.err.println(e);
        }
        finally{
             scan.close();
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

Mi duda es que no entiendo cómo hacer para Crear y regresa un ArrayList de perros que no han sido vacunados con base a la información de mi archivo, usando Iteradores. Esto no lo sé hacer, De qué forma se puede realizar esto ?

Comment: La respuesta no te ayudo? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300218/duda-con-respecto-a-como-a%c3%b1adir-contenido-de-un-archivo-de-texto-a-un-arraylist esta es la tercera pregunta que es similar.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes realizar la acción de 2 forma:

Primera y mas simple: 
Asumo que vacunas es de tipo Boolean = getVacunas() porque si es boolean seria isVacunas() cambialo según tu código:

```
try {
            scan = new Scanner (new FileReader(nombreArchivo));        
            while (scan.hasNext()) {


             Perro perro = new Perro(nombre, raza, peso, pedigree, vacunas);

             perro.setNombre(scan.next());             

             perro.setRaza(scan.next());             

             perro.setPeso(Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));             

             perro.setPedigree(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));             

             perro.setVacunas(Boolean.parseBoolean(scan.next()));                    

             //Si el registro cumple la condición se agrega en la lista que se retorna, asumo que vacunas es de tipo Boolean porque si es boolean seria isVacunas
             if(perro.getVacunas()){
                lista.add(perro);
             }

        }                
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println(e);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
         System.err.println(e);
    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e){
         System.err.println(e);
    }
    finally{
         scan.close();
    }

    return lista;
}
```

La segunda forma es con java 8, al final antes de retornar la lista filtramos con Stream

```
    // con este código llamamos el método stream() de la lista para poder realizar un filtro que cumpla con la condición vacunas == true y  lo que cumpla la condición lo recolectamos en un lista.
    return lista.stream().filter(Perro::getVacunas).collect(Collectors.toList());
```